# MySQL, PHP duplicates while under load

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php and mysql (mariadb specifically) for a basic registration of users. I sometimes have duplicates in my table (users created at the same second few times a week).
Of course I have in the PHP code a check (basic SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bla WHERE bla bla) if row with this specific email and other params exists. If yes then I know the duplicate exists. If not I create a new user (insert row).

This should theoretically work right. The problem is that between the SELECT and INSERT is quite a bit of other code and I assume theres a delay between these 2 operations under load when user somehow submits the registration form twice at the same time.

Is something like transaction going to prevent this? Does transaction lock the "users" table until it is commited so another parallel process cannot insert a row while the transaction is happening? Or is this something that transactions do not do?

I cannot create a unique key in the table because its not just about a duplicate email but other columns where the values differ (guest users can have duplicates and non-guest cannot).

this is allowed

email | guest

1. a@gmail.com     0
2. a@gmail.com     1
3. a@gmail.com     1

this is not

email | guest

1. a@gmail.com     0
2. a@gmail.com     0
3. a@gmail.com     1

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: @RidgeA can you create a unique key based on a value? To be more specific. I need to allow rows like this


1. email                         guest
2. abc@gmail.com      0
3. abc@gmail.com      1
4. abc@gmail.com      1

Comment: Transaction will block all table and it will cause performance downgrade.

Comment: @RidgeA I am aware of that. but can you make constraint that allows that. See my edited post. Basically only allow unique values where guest has value 0

Comment: @RidgeA - what? That's nonsense.

Comment: Transaction is a process that allows you to ensure all queries in the transactions executed successfully. If a single query fails, all of them fail. Transaction won't help you. Checking if record exists, be it on app or db level, won't help you. Locking the table won't help you. The only approach that will help you is placing an appropriate `unique` constraint.

Comment: @Mjh why doesnt locking table work? Lets say I lock table write before SELECT (for duplicates) and then if i dont find any duplicate I insert the row. Then I release lock. Afaik noone couldve changed the table while locked so it guarantees the row is unique. From performance standpoint its bad but in theory...

Comment: It won't work because you can, and trust me - you will, get into a situation where you acquire the lock but you don't release it. It happens often in concurrent environment. It won't happen immediately, but when it happens - it will wreak havoc. If you can't change an existing table, what prevents you from creating another table which holds hashes of people's details which act as unique key? That way you can, in one transaction, insert into your new table that acts as a check-table, then insert into your project's table. If a dupe occurs, unique constraint on 1st table will stop it.

Comment: ok thank you for explaining. nothing is preventing me really but Im just trying to find out the easiest possible solution if I can

Comment: If you want to prevent duplicates in your database, then the **only** way to do that is to place `unique` constraint(s) where appropriate, just like Danilo explained in his answer. Everything else will just produce problems. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

**You have to put a UNIQUE constraints in your table**

The UNIQUE constraint ensures that all values in a column are different.
You can have many UNIQUE constraints per table, but only one PRIMARY KEY constraint per table.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

use NULL value for your guest users, because a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL

**Another approch could be the use of a stored procedure**

Do not check if the user exists at application level, but create a stored procedure that atomically checks for duplicates and insert if possible

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-procedure.php

Comment: thank you for response. I didnt know this! Sadly this is not possible in my situation (big old project and I cannot just change this logic easily).

Comment: may be a stored procedure could be a solution for you?